# How to show a div when a button is clicked and then scroll to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to show a div when a button is clicked and then scroll to it? I am using the following code. It shows the div, but I have to click on the button again to scroll to the div. Is there a way to maybe make the button click twice?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#home-btn-1").on('click', function () {

     $('div.hide-section-mobile').addClass("show");
      $('#home-btn-1').scrollTo('#funnel-1-mobile');
  });
});
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Comment: I don't know why my answer got downvoted, But here is a working example using `location.hash` http://jsfiddle.net/43Ls1tnd/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extend your logic, in the click event at a check to see if the class is revealed. If it is scroll to it, I modified my code to work in the example below:

```js
$("#home-btn").on('click', function() {
  $('#funnel-1-mobile').hasClass("show") ? console.log('Adding') : $('#funnel-1-mobile').addClass("show");
  $(window).scrollTop(1500);
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#funnel-1-mobile {
  background-color: indigo;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='home-btn'>Click to scroll</button>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<div id='funnel-1-mobile'>I scrolled!</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but just as before, in mobile it only shows it, it doesn't scroll to it unless I click a 2nd time on the same button

This is the site http://maritimeinjuryfirm.com/test445-copy/

When I click on "Get more information" I need it to reveal the next div in mobile, which it does, and then scroll to it.

Comment: Oh I see you want to do both in one click. I didn't understand your question properly

Comment: Is there a way to make the button click itself twice?

Comment: Hmm you could, simply use `trigger('click')` in the else case. That way when you click it once it adds the class and immediately calls itself triggering the scroll

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: @DayanCabrera just following up, did the above help you at all? Or are you still having issues?

Comment: I am about to try it right now. I will let you know the result asap. Thanks so much for all the help :)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("div#home-btn-1").on('click', function () { 
        $('div.hide-section-mobile').addClass("show").scrollIntoView();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.hash = "elementID";`

Replace `$('#home-btn-1').scrollTo('#funnel-1-mobile');`

With `location.hash = 'funnel-1-mobile';`

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/43Ls1tnd/7/

Comment: Why my answer is downvoted, Although it's working?

Comment: It doesn't work on mobile sadly :/ It shows the div on the first click, but wont scroll to it unless I click on it again.

This is the site http://maritimeinjuryfirm.com/test445-copy/

When I click on "Get more information" I need it to reveal the next div in mobile, which it does, and then scroll to it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the button click itself twice?

Comment: It's doing both when the button is clicked once, Did you tried my code and my example above?

Comment: First, There is an anchor that scrolls to the element, So you could either remove the scroll part or the anchor

Comment: If you want to click it twice, Use that and it will be clicked again after you click it once, `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#home-btn-1").on('click', function () {

     $('div.hide-section-mobile').addClass("show");
      $('#home-btn-1').scrollTo('#funnel-1-mobile');
    $('div#home-btn-1').click();
  });
});`